# Accessing this inside each loop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why does this code only works with `$(this)` inside the `$.each` loop, and stops working when I use `col` argument instead. Isn't that how it supposed to work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = $('div.row');
  $.each(rows, function() {
    var row = $(this);
    row.find('div.col-sm-6').each(function(index, col) {
      $(col).removeClass('col-sm-push-6');
      $(col).removeClass('col-sm-pull-6');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" style="display: block;">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
    <br style="clear:both;">
    <div class="RIF_Csp2" id="yourCsp2" style="float:left;"><span class="RIF_Field RIF_State" id="yourState" style="display: none;"><label class="fldLbl" id="yourStateLabel">State:</label><br>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><select id="yourStateValue" name="yourState" onchange="null" onfocus="null" onblur="null" tabindex="0"><option value="">Select One</option></select><img alt="" height="9" id="yourStateReqdImg" src="/img/1.gif" width="11"></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
    <br style="clear:both;">
    <div class="RIF_Csp3" id="yourCsp3" style="float:left;"><span class="RIF_Field RIF_Postal" id="yourPostal" style="width: 200px;"><label class="fldLbl" id="yourPostalLabel">ZIP Code:</label><br>
<span style="white-space: nowrap;"><input id="yourPostalValue" maxlength="15" name="yourPostal" size="15" style="width:200px;" type="text" tabindex="0"><img alt="Required" height="9" id="yourPostalReqdImg" src="/img/icn_dia.gif" width="11"></span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `col` or `$(col)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Use `$(col)`, not `col`.

**Long answer**

`col` argument is the same as using `this`. If you are replacing `$(this)` you should use `$(col)`. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = $('div.row');
  $.each(rows, function() {
    var row = $(this);
    row.find('div.col-sm-6').each(function(index, col) {
      $(col).removeClass('col-sm-push-6');
      $(col).removeClass('col-sm-pull-6');
    });
  });
});
```

The array that `.each` loops inside `row.find('div.col-sm-6')` is actually an array of the DOM elements. So, if you want to use jQuery methods like `.removeClass` you should wrap it with `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$(this)` instead of `this` for the same reason.

`$(col)` is the jQuery object for that element, just like with `this`/`$(this)`.